How to write data to an on prem Postgresql db from Synapse?
I am trying to write data to an on prem Postgresql db from Synapse. I used two approaches but still not successful.

Created a dataflow for ETL but on prem Postgresql db is not supported as a sink by Synapse(link).
Tried performing ETL using PySpark notebook and used psycopg2 for writing data to the Postgresql db, but getting the following error:

(psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "xx.x.xx.xx",
    port 5432 failed: Connection timed out Is the server running on that
    host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Is there any workaround that I can use to write data to the on prem Postgresql db from Synapse?

Is your Postgres configured to listen for socket connections?  That's in pg_hba.conf.


(psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "xx.x.xx.xx",
port 5432 failed: Connection timed out Is the server running on that
host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

The above error you are getting is because of Synapse notebook is unable to establish a connection to the PostgreSQL server at the specified IP address and port.

Check if your IP address and port number is correct to read the Postgres sql server.
The PostgreSQL server may not be configured to accept connections from your IP address. Check the pg_hba.conf file on the server to ensure that your IP address is allowed to connect.
Check if your firewall is not blocking the port and connection.


Is there any workaround that I can use to write data to the on prem Postgresql db from Synapse?

You can use JDBC driver to connect with Azure PostgreSQL database in Synapse PySpark Notebook.
url = "jdbc:postgresql://your_postgresql_server:5432/your_database"

properties = {
    "user": "your_username",
    "password": "your_password",
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
}

result_table_name = "your_result_table"

filtered_df.write.jdbc(url, result_table_name, mode="overwrite", properties=properties)

Also, you can refer this MS QnA answer for similar issue

Hi Pratik, thanks for your answer. Can you please let me know where I can find Azure Synapse IP address that I should add in pg_hba.conf?
